# Low perfomence of c# code running without admin priveleges

Tags: c#, performance, sql-server-ce

I have a program written in c# (framework 4.0).
There I use entity framework with SQL CE 4.0, LINQ to XML.

When I start it with admin account, it works fine. If I launch it with user account, its performance falls down terribly. Perfomance of all components: LINQ, EF.
For example loading some data from xml-file to database with admin account takes about 1 minute, but with user account it takes 4 hours.

This problem only occurs on **Windows XP** machine when using an **encrypted SQL CE database**.

Have anybody some ideas in which direction I must think to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: how can we help without knowing how do you perform the action ?

Comment: Have you tried redgate and/or dottrace? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers Perhaps it has to do with drive encryption: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eb6a01a7-0bfd-41e3-b4c8-34581c5ccaa3/sql-compact-4-locks-up-30seconds-when-accessing-encrypted-database-on-windows-xp-when-running-in with the profiler, you can verify if it is the xml and linq part that is slow or the sql/database part

Comment: Sounds like poor network performances...

Comment: Are the users being looked up from an Active Directory or are they local users?

Comment: I use win xp and it was trouble with encription. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a valid question. About a year a go a spent a lot of time and ended up using one of our Support Incidents with Microsoft to get to the bottom of this issue. See my answer below for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known (at least to me and Microsoft) problem with SQL CE, Windows XP and encryption.

To solve the performance bottleneck grant `All Users` Read access to this folder: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`